# memory efficient Python (pandas) aggregates of categories from one csv file per period

Tags: python, csv, pandas, segmentation-fault

I am trying to avoid a segmentation fault with either pandas or IOPro (still investigating), so I am looking for alternative solutions, esp. more efficient ones. The code below runs fine with small data but crashed reading in 90 monthly panels of a few GBs on a Linux server with 256 GB RAM, versions pandas 0.16.2 np19py26_0, iopro 1.7.1 np19py27_p0, and python 2.7.10 0.

What I do here is that I aggregate accounts of drug purchase records (cost in TKOST) for each person (LopNr) and month, while also separating the drugs into categories using their ATC codes.

So while the original data would look like this, in monthly csv files (say July 2006 here, with many other columns in the csv I don't need):

```
LopNr TKOST ATC
1         5 N01
1        11 N01
1         6 N15
```

etc.

I wanted aggregate panels, with rows like

```
LopNr TKOST year month
1        22 2006     7
```

either separately for a few categories (e.g. neuro for ATCs starting with N here), or with separate summaries for these categories in a single datafile (so with a neuro column etc.).

I opted for IOPro and not simple pandas to be more efficient with memory, but now I am getting a segmentation error.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import iopro
from pandas import *

neuro   = DataFrame()
cardio  = DataFrame()
cancer  = DataFrame()
addiction  = DataFrame()
Adrugs  = DataFrame()
Mdrugs  = DataFrame()
Vdrugs  = DataFrame()
all_drugs  = DataFrame()

for year in xrange(2005,2013):
    for month in xrange(1,13):
        if year == 2005 and month < 7:
            continue
        filename = 'PATH/lmed_' + str(year) + '_mon'+ str(month) +'.txt'
        adapter = iopro.text_adapter(filename,parser='csv',field_names=True,output='dataframe',delimiter='\t')
        monthly = adapter[['LopNr','ATC','TKOST']][:]
        monthly['year']=year
        monthly['month']=month
        neuro = neuro.append(monthly[(monthly.ATC.str.startswith('N')) & (~(monthly.TKOST.isnull()))])
        cardio = cardio.append(monthly[(monthly.ATC.str.startswith('C')) & (~(monthly.TKOST.isnull()))])
        cancer = cancer.append(monthly[(monthly.ATC.str.startswith('L')) & (~(monthly.TKOST.isnull()))])
        addiction = addiction.append(monthly[(monthly.ATC.str.startswith('N07')) & (~(monthly.TKOST.isnull()))])
        Adrugs = Adrugs.append(monthly[(monthly.ATC.str.startswith('A')) & (~(monthly.TKOST.isnull()))])
        Mdrugs = Mdrugs.append(monthly[(monthly.ATC.str.startswith('M')) & (~(monthly.TKOST.isnull()))])
        Vdrugs = Vdrugs.append(monthly[(monthly.ATC.str.startswith('V')) & (~(monthly.TKOST.isnull()))])
        all_drugs = all_drugs.append(monthly[(~(monthly.TKOST.isnull()))])
        del monthly

all_drugs = all_drugs.groupby(['LopNr','year','month']).sum()
all_drugs = all_drugs.astype(int,copy=False)
all_drugs.to_csv('PATH/monthly_all_drugs_costs.csv')
del all_drugs

neuro = neuro.groupby(['LopNr','year','month']).sum()
neuro = neuro.astype(int,copy=False)
neuro.to_csv('PATH/monthly_neuro_costs.csv')
del neuro

cardio = cardio.groupby(['LopNr','year','month']).sum()
cardio = cardio.astype(int,copy=False)
cardio.to_csv('PATH/monthly_cardio_costs.csv')
del cardio

cancer = cancer.groupby(['LopNr','year','month']).sum()
cancer = cancer.astype(int,copy=False)
cancer.to_csv('PATH/monthly_cancer_costs.csv')
del cancer

addiction = addiction.groupby(['LopNr','year','month']).sum()
addiction = addiction.astype(int,copy=False)
addiction.to_csv('PATH/monthly_addiction_costs.csv')
del addiction

Adrugs = Adrugs.groupby(['LopNr','year','month']).sum()
Adrugs = Adrugs.astype(int,copy=False)
Adrugs.to_csv('PATH/monthly_Adrugs_costs.csv')
del Adrugs

Mdrugs = Mdrugs.groupby(['LopNr','year','month']).sum()
Mdrugs = Mdrugs.astype(int,copy=False)
Mdrugs.to_csv('PATH/monthly_Mdrugs_costs.csv')
del Mdrugs

Vdrugs = Vdrugs.groupby(['LopNr','year','month']).sum()
Vdrugs = Vdrugs.astype(int,copy=False)
Vdrugs.to_csv('PATH/monthly_Vdrugs_costs.csv')
del Vdrugs
```

Comment: Have you looked into HDF5 at all?  I think that's probably the most standard way to store binary/compressed data in pandas.  Though not the only way and I'm not sure how it compares to IOPro overall.  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with storage method, but you could consider how you are storing your variables.  For example, you'll save memory storing date as a single datetime column vs separate year and month columns, and storing 'ATC' as a categorical rather than string/object.

Comment: and you really need to edit/simplify the question  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Category for ATC is a neat improvement — but would break my parsing, no? But OK, I'd see priorities better after some proper profiling. Point taken.

Comment: Yeah, it would break it but you can replace `ATC.str` with `ATC.astype(str).str`.  It's just a matter of whether that is sufficiently helpful or not with memory to be worth the bother.

Comment: Note that I could avoid the segfault by avoiding IOPro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is quite repetitive and could be simplified with dictionary and list comprehensions.  This solution should eliminate your memory issues, as you only process one month's data at a time (although you have a growing list of monthly summaries which I don't believe will use much memory).

I can't test this, but I believe it will do everything in your code above.

```
import pandas as pd
import iopro

items = {'neuro': 'N', 
         'cardio': 'C', 
         'cancer': 'L', 
         'addiction': 'N07', 
         'Adrugs': 'A', 
         'Mdrugs': 'M', 
         'Vdrugs': 'V', 
         'all_drugs': ''}

# 1. Create data container using dictionary comprehension.
monthly_summaries = {item: list() for item in items.keys()}

# 2. Perform monthly groupby operations.
for year in xrange(2005, 2013):
    for month in xrange(1, 13):
        if year == 2005 and month < 7:
            continue
        filename = 'PATH/lmed_' + str(year) + '_mon'+ str(month) +'.txt'
        adapter = iopro.text_adapter(filename,
                                     parser='csv', 
                                     field_names=True, 
                                     output='data frame', 
                                     delimiter='\t')
        monthly = adapter[['LopNr','ATC','TKOST']][:]
        monthly['year'] = year
        monthly['month'] = month
        dfs = {name: monthly[(monthly.ATC.str.startswith('{0}'.format(code))) 
                             & (~(monthly.TKOST.isnull()))]
                     for name, code in items.iteritems()}
        [monthly_summaries[name].append(dfs[name].groupby(['LopNr','year','month']).sum()
                                        .astype(int, copy=False)) 
         for name in items.keys()]

# 3. Now concatenate all of the monthly summaries into separate DataFrames.
dfs = {name: pd.concat([monthly_summaries[name], ignore_axis=True]) 
       for name in items.keys()}

# 4. Now regroup the aggregate monthly summaries.
monthly_summaries = {name: dfs[name].reset_index().groupby(['LopNr','year','month']).sum()
                    for name in items.keys()}

# 5. Finally, save the aggregated results to files.
[monthly_summaries[name].to_csv('PATH/monthly_{0}_costs.csv'.format(name))
 for name in items()]
```

Comment: This is a nice way forward, and answers this question. Without asking a separate one though: Could I somehow loop over three variables which to select and then sum up? I think the current code sums up binary indicators, right? I would love to have it multiplied/weighted with the TKOST variable [i.e. the TKOST summed up selectively only for rows satisfying a condition], and a new one I'd also read in now.

Comment: I am also confused by the use of two groupby's in your solution. Why do we need/do that? I also tried to adapt the code for another use case, and get a `'dict' object is not callable` error in the very last line, I wonder what could change, if everything else seems to run fine.

Comment: By recollection, there are two groupby operations because of the memory constraint.  The first summarizes each month's data, and second groups on the monthly summaries. `dfs` in 3. (now concatenate all of...) is a dataframe indexed on row numbers.  It looks like the second groupby only reindexes this dataframe on 'LopNr', 'year' and 'month' which would get flattened when wrote it to a csv file, so probably isn't necessary.

Comment: The  'dict' object is not callable error generally occurs when you access a dictionary value using parentheses instead of brackets (e.g. dict('key') vs. dict['key']).

Comment: Regarding your first comment, you would need to create a new column in dfs (part 2.) which is the weighted sum. Then you would perform the groupby ([monthly_summaries[name].append(dfs[name].groupby...)